# MVC3 referencing update-able dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reference, assemblies, gac

I would like create a MVC3 website. I have existing dlls packaged as .net MSI which are installed into the GAC. What is the best way to reference these update-able dlls in MVC3? They will always be installed into the GAC, their version number will be updated accordingly. I don't want to have to manually reference them in my MVC3 project, as every time I re install, the reference will break and I have to update my dependent dll references.

Any input would be appreciated. I have looked around for solutions already but nothing seems straight forward.

Thanks

Comment: You don't appear to understand the purpose of the GAC. It's actually largely to prevent/avoid what you are trying to do.

Comment: why would you want to update your dev environment, with every increment of a dependent module? what is wrong with having it work seamlessly?

Comment: The GAC is meant to avoid the old "DLL-Hell" by including versioning - you can have multiple versions of the same assembly there; your project will only work with the one(s) it was meant to work with. If you just install a new version of an assembly without recompiling the program that uses it, the program will continue to use the old version, because that's what it was meant to use. The new one will *also* be in the GAC... but if you don't have any programs that were compiled against that version, it won't be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't found a solution because there isn't one. In order for an assembly to be installed into the GAC it must have a strong name. Every application that uses assemblies from the GAC are tied to the given version and strong name (and this no matter whether you statically referenced the assembly at compile time or used reflection to load it). If you modify it in the GAC clients no longer work and should be updated accordingly. So if you intend to often modify versions of the assembly the GAC is probably not the right place for you. You could still make changes to an assembly in the GAC without modifying its version but you must ensure that those changes are compatible in order to avoid breaking clients.

Comment: if GAC is not the correct place. Then what are the alternatives? In an ideal world? I can't change the existing process of how the dependent modules are updated.

Comment: I can actually update my web.config file with   <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MY.Asssembly.Func1" publicKeyToken="qwertyuip" Culture="neutral"/>
      </dependentAssembly> . this will tell VS to udpate to the latest reference in GAC. It should make the site look for the updated dlls in GAC. Unfortunately, if I was to compile my source, it will still break, as there are still older dll references in the .csprog files. You are correct there is no solution, without an update in the source file to accomamdate version udpate!